# opencv python code equivalent in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have this piece of code that works fine on Python.
I want to do the same thing in C/C++ but i do not understand how works kernel in C++:

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
```

kernel and opening are Mat objects.

I have also

```
mat1=np.uint8(mat1)
```

I do not understand what is this np prefix.

Comment: The `np` prefix is the `numpy` library. OpenCV uses that library for all numeric operations, because Python arrays are very inefficient for numeric computations.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
kernal = np.ones((3,3)), np.uint8)
```

is the same as doing this in C++:

```
Mat m = Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(1));
```

As `MaruisSiuram` said the np prefix is for the numpy library, this is not used in C++ you can just use the OpenCV Matrix container.

This line:

```
mat1=np.uint8(mat1)
```

is casting mat1 to the type uint8 which can be done like so:

```
mat1.convertTo(mat1, CV_8UC1);
```

Comment: Two problems that I see: 1. kernel should be 8UC1, 2. `1` might be interpreted as data address. So `Mat m = Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(1));` or `Mat m = Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_8UC1);`

Comment: I know it defaults to "1" so ive updated with the more obvious scalar solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.
Another question: In python we can do this: mat1[mat2==255] = 0. What is the equivalent en C++ ?

Comment: You may want also to mention `getStructuringElement()`. @testpresta `mat1.setTo(0, mat2 == 255);`